# Access RDS using .net core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, rds, c#-6.0

I am new to .net core. I want to access RDS using .net core. It would be great if I can get steps to be followed for the same or some code sample. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How to access your DB running in RDS will vary depending on what engine you have selected.  You'll want to use whatever driver is appropriate for the engine you've selected.  For example, you'll need to choose a mySql driver if you picked mySql or Aurora; a T-SQL driver if you've gone with MS SQL Server; and so on.  RDS is simply hosting your DB, and doesn't prescribe to you a particular client library.

Comment: Can you please share link for the same. i am using .net core 1.1 and i am using mysql database.

Comment: it be really cool if they made it one click where you didn't have to install dependencies, etc